Как в моем коде бота на telebot реализовать проверку подписан пользователь или нет?
Я решил сделать бота для показа фильмов я в нем реализовал уже все функции, кроме проверки на то подписан человек или нет.
P.S. - Буду вам очень признателен если вы подскажите где нужно поменять и дополнить код.
Код находится по этой ссылке: https://github.com/ITGOComp/Bot

Предоставьте тот участок кода, с которым у Вас проблемы и покажите свои попытки решить её. Здесь за Вас никто не будет делать работу.
Также, задача расплывчатая. Подписан на что?

если нужна проверка подписки на чат (группа/канал) - для этого есть метод getChatMember().

chat_id - id или @channelusername канала
user_id - id пользователя

При этом у бота, находящегося в этом канале, должны быть права администратора.
